# How can I output a column twice and with different values based on another table's reference?

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

I have two tables `message` and `person`:

1. `message` table contains columns `receiverID` and `senderID`
2. `person` table contains columns `name` and `personID`

`personID` and `receiverID/senderID` can be used to connect the tables

I'm having trouble outputting the name column twice, once based on the `receiverID` and the second based on `senderID` using the `WHERE` clause.
I am only able to output name once based on `personID = senderID`.

```
SELECT person.first_name AS senderFirstName,     
(SELECT person.first_name FROM person, message WHERE person_id = receiver_id)    
FROM person, message   WHERE person_id = sender_id AND sender_id = 1;
```

This produces an `ERROR 1242 (21000): Subquery returns more than 1 row`.
I just have no idea what to try next...very new to SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need this:

```
SELECT 
person.first_name AS senderFirstName, 
(SELECT p2.first_name FROM person p2 WHERE p2.person_id = 
m.receiver_id)receiveFirstName
FROM person p , message m 
WHERE p.person_id = m.sender_id AND m.sender_id = 1;
```

Comment: YESSS!! thank you, I didn't know to use the p2 renaming ability and the ability to alias the column after the parentheses. THANK YOU!

Comment: @PFKB if that solved you question give it a green tick others following the form will be benefitted!!!!

Answer (score 2):

You need to join the table `person` twice to the table `message`:

```
select s.name, ...
from message m
inner join person s on m.senderid = s.personid
inner join person r on m.receiverid = r.personid
where m.senderid = 1
```

Comment: Thanks! Seems more efficient but my homework requires using the WHERE clause only, without joining.